# How do you scan an area for a certain block? (JAVA 1.17.1)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm currently working on a Minecraft minigame where the goal is for Team A to collect all the torches and Team B's goal is to kill Team A (basically Pac-Man(or dark deception)) and I'm asking: How do I tell when the torches are all gone within a certain radius?

Answer (score 1):

While my command block skills are outdated at best, I suppose having an invisible armour stand or an AoE cloud at the location of each torch could work. You could then have a scoreboard var that is set to 0, and have each entity that doesn't detect a torch increment that. If the var is smaller than the number of torches, reset the var, else the torch team wins. Note that this is only viable if you control the location of all torches and torches can't be placed.

Another way is to keep track of torch-related [statistics](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Statistics). This is the most difficult but most flexible approach, as this could allow free placing and breaking of the torches.

The third way would be to clear picked up torches from the inventory, incrementing a scoreboard var on success. This allows for free placement, but not for placing torches.

Nice idea, post a link if you ever finished this!